# How to install Google Protobuf in MacBook Pro in Apple M1 chip?

Tags: protocol-buffers, apple-m1

I want to know how to install protoBuf in MacBook Pro in Apple M1 chip. Anyone known the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that protocol buffers are still migrating to M1 support. Until then, you can presumably run them with Rosetta2's x86 emulation. They'll show up in [the releases page.](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/)

Edit: As of version 21 (May, 2022), there is a "Universal build" (see the releases page).

Answer (score 3):

you can use
`arch -x86_64 zsh`
this command lets the your shell run under Rosetta2.
then you can install the protobuf with  `brew install protobuf@version`

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention, you could build it from source if needed. I came across this article that worked for me for this same problem you posted, that gives the steps to build from source.

https://medium.com/@danny4410.eecs04/install-protobuf-on-m1-mac-852e4afa619f

I was building for a specific version, so it was easier for me to just download the source for the given release and build rather than git pull the intended version tag to build that.